# Double pole, double zero: incorrect plot?

Tags: boost, matlab, bode-plot, compensation, loop-gain

I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong here. Suppose I want a double pole, double zero system that looks like this:

$$ \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{s}{\omega_z}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{s}{\omega_z}\right)}{\left(1+\dfrac{s}{\omega_p}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{s}{\omega_p}\right)}$$

and I plot its frequency response. I think I should see the peak phase boost occurring at the geometric mean of the two frequencies, so
$$f_\text{peak} = \sqrt{f_p \times f_z} $$

I set this peak frequency to 3 kHz, and pick
$$f_p = kf_\text{peak} = 2.75 \cdot 3 = 8.25 \ \mathrm{kHz}$$
$$f_Z = f_\text{peak}/k = 3/2.75 = 1.09 \ \mathrm{kHz}$$

I wrote this piece of code in MATLAB, but it's not showing the peak at 3 kHz frequency. What am I missing here?

```
DPZ = ((1+s/1090.9)^2/(1+s/8242.4)^2)
bode(DPZ,Bopt);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to multiply the hertz by \$2\pi\$ in your matlab code. So with a peak around 470 Hz shown on your graph, if you multiply this by \$2\pi\$ you'll get 2953 Hz as a corrected value.

[image]

Radians per second = Hz × \$2\pi\$.

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up "f" (regular frequency) and "omega" (angular frequency). As a result, your frequency response is off by a factor 2pi.

Your formula expected omega, but you plugged in the values for f.

omega=2pi*f